# pepperに歌わせたり踊らせるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか

Tags: pepper

pepperのヘビーローテーションやマルモリなどのダンスのアプリがありますが、あのようにpepperを歌わせたり、踊らせたりするにはどのようなソフトが必要なのでしょうか。また、どのようにして作るのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Pepperの動作のためにはまずはChoregrapheと呼ばれる専用のデスクトップアプリケーションを用います。

https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/jp-ja/faq/choregraphe%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%9F

更に複雑な動きや情報処理をする場合は幾つかの言語に対応したSDKが購入者向けに公開されています。

さらなる詳細はこちらでひとつひとつ説明するよりもソフトバンクの開発サポートのサイトがありますのでそちらを参考にしてもらったほうがいいかもしれません。
https://www.softbank.jp/robot/developer/tools/document/